# How do I remove unnecessary whitespace here?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having some trouble removing some whitespace, which looks to be pre-generated by Wordpress. The computed layout of the section including the whitespace is as follows for :

[image]

Here is what the current result looks like:

[image]

I'm not immediately seeing how the whitespace is being added here.

EDIT: This is the section of code that is causing issues. The computed layout for `entry-content` is above. The div starting with `wp-block-group` is the start of the content, and the whitespace is not highlighted when this is selected.

```
<div class="entry-content">
::before        
<div class="wp-block-group alignfull has-foreground-background-color has-background is-layout-constrained"><div class="wp-block-group__inner-container"><div class="wp-block-image">
<figure class="aligncenter size-medium"><img data-attachment-id="116" data-permalink="https://bolestech.com/boles-technologies/original-logo/" data-orig-file="https://hunterb9101.files.wordpress.com/2023/03/original-logo.png" data-orig-size="2300,1533" data-comments-opened="1" data-image-meta="{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}" data-image-title="original-logo" data-image-description="" data-image-caption="" data-medium-file="https://hunterb9101.files.wordpress.com/2023/03/original-logo.png?w=300" data-large-file="https://hunterb9101.files.wordpress.com/2023/03/original-logo.png?w=750" src="https://hunterb9101.files.wordpress.com/2023/03/original-logo.png?w=300" alt="" class="wp-image-116" srcset="https://hunterb9101.files.wordpress.com/2023/03/original-logo.png?w=300 300w, https://hunterb9101.files.wordpress.com/2023/03/original-logo.png?w=600 600w, https://hunterb9101.files.wordpress.com/2023/03/original-logo.png?w=150 150w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" /></figure></div>


<hr class="wp-block-separator has-text-color has-background-color has-alpha-channel-opacity has-background-background-color has-background is-style-wide" style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0" />


<nav class="is-responsive items-justified-center wp-block-navigation is-content-justification-center is-layout-flex wp-container-2" aria-label="Primary"><button aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Open menu" class="wp-block-navigation__responsive-container-open " data-micromodal-trigger="modal-1"><svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><rect x="4" y="7.5" width="16" height="1.5" /><rect x="4" y="15" width="16" height="1.5" /></svg></button>
            <div class="wp-block-navigation__responsive-container  " style="" id="modal-1">
                <div class="wp-block-navigation__responsive-close" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
                    <div class="wp-block-navigation__responsive-dialog" aria-label="Menu">
                            <button aria-label="Close menu" data-micromodal-close class="wp-block-navigation__responsive-container-close"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"><path d="M13 11.8l6.1-6.3-1-1-6.1 6.2-6.1-6.2-1 1 6.1 6.3-6.5 6.7 1 1 6.5-6.6 6.5 6.6 1-1z"></path></svg></button>
                        <div class="wp-block-navigation__responsive-container-content" id="modal-1-content">
                            <ul class="wp-block-page-list has-large-font-size"><li class="wp-block-pages-list__item wp-block-navigation-item open-on-hover-click menu-item-home"><a class="wp-block-pages-list__item__link wp-block-navigation-item__content" href="https://bolestech.com/">Home</a></li><li class="wp-block-pages-list__item wp-block-navigation-item open-on-hover-click"><a class="wp-block-pages-list__item__link wp-block-navigation-item__content" href="https://bolestech.com/about/">About</a></li><li class="wp-block-pages-list__item current-menu-item wp-block-navigation-item open-on-hover-click"><a class="wp-block-pages-list__item__link wp-block-navigation-item__content" href="https://bolestech.com/contact/" aria-current="page">Contact</a></li></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></nav></div></div>
...
```

Comment: It's difficult to predict what is causing it just by looking at the image. You can use the arrow which helps select the element in the page to identify the culprit. I believe a margin on the header might be the issue

Comment: Sorry, we cannot debug pictures only code.

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi Yeah, I totally get where you guys are coming from. The only element which highlights is a singular div with the following computed layout. A hosted site with the issue is shown here: https://bolestech.com/contact/.

Comment: @Hunter the entry-content is being influenced by many margin-top properties. Assuming u want the easiest solution, just edit it as `<div class="entry-content" style="margin-top: 0;">`

Answer (score -1):

In the inspector, use this tool and click on the whitespace.

[image]

You will probably be able to see where the margin/padding comes from.